# shinyapps says Python package not installed after just installing it

Tags: shiny, shinyapps, reticulate

I am having trouble deploying to shinyapps.io a Shiny app using reticulate and sklearn. It worked in the past which is strange.

My showLogs show that the sklearn was installed OK, but then it fails. See bold bits.

> 2022-12-01T05:35:31.072753+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Building wheels
> for collected packages: sklearn 2022-12-01T05:35:31.073424+00:00
> shinyapps[6354935]:   Building wheel for sklearn (setup.py): started
> **2022-12-01T05:35:31.376650+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]:   Building wheel
> for sklearn (setup.py): finished with status 'done'**
> 2022-12-01T05:35:31.377240+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]:   Created wheel
> for sklearn: filename=sklearn-0.0.post1-py3-none-any.whl size=2935
> sha256=afa8f4d2a5d1eb8c1108cc46573eee0243edf28ccc4daa14e1653f95f374ef73
> 2022-12-01T05:35:31.377410+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]:   Stored in
> directory:
> /home/shiny/.cache/pip/wheels/1c/2f/26/476423e3abcbdc095c9061b4a385339f4d5c4952c036ef8262
> **2022-12-01T05:35:31.379641+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Successfully
> built sklearn**
> 2022-12-01T05:35:31.474083+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]:
> Installing collected packages: sklearn, pytz, zope.interface, six,
> pyparsing, pillow, kiwisolver, fonttools, cycler, contourpy,
> python-dateutil, packaging, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, wordcloud
> 2022-12-01T05:35:42.219143+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Successfully
> installed contourpy-1.0.6 cycler-0.11.0 datetime-4.7 fonttools-4.38.0
> kiwisolver-1.4.4 matplotlib-3.6.2 packaging-21.3 pandas-1.5.2
> pillow-9.3.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.6
> six-1.16.0 sklearn-0.0.post1 wordcloud-1.8.2.2 zope.interface-5.5.2
> 2022-12-01T05:35:48.964346+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Matplotlib is
> building the font cache; this may take a moment.
> 2022-12-01T05:35:51.393586+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Error in
> value[3L] :  2022-12-01T05:35:51.393620+00:00
> **shinyapps[6354935]:   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'**
> 2022-12-01T05:35:51.393625+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Calls: local ...
> tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
> 2022-12-01T05:35:51.393629+00:00 shinyapps[6354935]: Execution halted

I am creating a virtualenv when it sees user Shiny. I was using this [guidance](https://github.com/ranikay/shiny-reticulate-app).

```
if (Sys.info()[['user']] == 'shiny'){
  # When running on shinyapps.io, create a virtualenv
  envs<-reticulate::virtualenv_list()
  if(!'venv_shiny_app' %in% envs)
  {
    reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'venv_shiny_app',
                                  python = 'python3')
    reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app',
                                   packages = c('matplotlib',
                                                'pandas',
                                                'numpy',
                                                'wordcloud',
                                                'sklearn',
                                                'datetime'))
  }
  # https://github.com/ranikay/shiny-reticulate-app
  # Set environment BEFORE this
  reticulate::use_virtualenv('venv_shiny_app', required = TRUE)

} else {
  print(paste0("User: ", Sys.info()[['user']]))
}
```

When I call from global.R the source:

```
source_python("code/dash-babbleapp-fun.py")
```

It is going to a script that has this code.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS as sk_stopwords
```

Is this the problem that a subset of sklearn is not being seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `scikit-learn` in your `requirements` file/run `pip install scikit-learn`?

The package was renamed from `sklearn` to `scikit-learn` so that may be the reason why you're now unable to import `sklearn` (see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8215). This brownout change started on December 1st, so it is probably no coincidence.